# Sql Server rows being auto inserted without a trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in sql server, for which, if I delete a row from it, a new row is inserted with the same data, and userid as the one I deleted.  There are no triggers on this table.  In addition, I did a search of all database objects that reference this table, and there are no triggers anywhere in the database that reference this table, only some stored procedures, none of which have any code that would cause this behavior.

To be clear, if I run this query:

```
delete from my_table where id = 1
```

the row with the id of `1` will be deleted, but a new row will be inserted that has the same userid, and date as the deleted row.  No application code involved, just a straight sql delete statement run directly on the database causes this.

What else besides a trigger could be causing this to happen?  I've never encountered something like this before.

Comment: How do you know that the row is actually being deleted?

Comment: Is it a new row being inserted, or just the same row that never got deleted in the first place?  Maybe there is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger for delete only...

Comment: @Lamak because i run a select statement for rows with that userid, and the original row is gone.

Comment: So the "deleted" row and the "new inserted" row have a different `id` value?

Comment: And how long afterwards is the "same row" inserted again?, can you run a profiler?

Comment: @DMason yes, that's correct.  the "new inserted" row has a new id.

Comment: Then I would run a profiler trace, as @Lamak suggests.

Comment: Also consider if someone used dynamic SQL in a SP, building up a string then executing it as SQL, it wouldn't show up in a references search.  I agree profiler is best approach, otherwise you'll be chasing guesses all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a long time, but I discovered this was being caused by a "rogue" linq-to-sql dll that was running in spite of it's parent app being killed.

The good news is, there isn't some weird non-trigger way to insert rows on delete in SQL, so we can all resume our normal lives now, knowing all is as it was.